# $\mathit C(K)$ the space of continuous functions from a compact metric space $\mathit K$ to the complex field is banach

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\mathit K$ be a compact metric space and $\mathit C(K)$ the space of continuous functions from $\mathit K$ to the complex field. I am trying to show $\mathit C(K)$ is a banach space with respect to the supremum norm.

My attempt:

Given a cauchy sequence $\mathit (f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $\mathit C(K)$ the pointwise limit of the sequence exists, denote it $\mathit f$. We want to show that $\mathit f_n \to f$ uniformly. I've tried taking a dense subset of $\mathit K$ and manipulating but it seems to lead nowhere. I also tried to first show $\mathit f$ itself is continuous but not only I failed to do so but I also cannot see how to finish from there.

I should state that I tried to find posts on that problem but I only found one that uses cauchy summability criteria which I am not allowed to use.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the fact that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy with respect to the sup norm, not just that it converges pointwise to $f$.

Comment: Oh I think I can see it, $|\mathit f(x) - f_n(x)| = lim_{m\to\infty}{|\mathit f_m(x) - f_n(x)|}<\varepsilon$. Is that true?

Comment: @EricWofsey If what I wrote is true then I don't see how we use compactness of K (or even the fact it is a metric space)

Comment: @OfekArian For the sup norm of $f$ to be finite, you need $f$ to be bounded.

Answer (score 0):

You've already shown $f_n\to f$ pointwise for some $f:K\to\mathbb{C}$. Let's note that $f$ is bounded since $\{f_n:n\geq N\}$ is a uniformly bounded set of functions for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

**a.** For each $x\in K$ and each $m,n\geq N$, we have $$|f(x)-f_n(x)|\leq |f(x)-f_m(x)| + \|f_n-f_m\|_{\infty}$$ where $\|g\|_{\infty}:=\sup\{|g(x)|:x\in K\}$. As $m\to\infty$ we get $$|f(x)-f_n(x)|\leq \limsup_{m\to\infty}\|f_n-f_m\|_{\infty}.$$ The right hand side doesn't depent on $x\in K$, thus $$\|f-f_n\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in K}|f(x)-f_n(x)|\leq \limsup_{m\to\infty}\|f_n-f_m\|_{\infty}.$$ Finally, as $n\to\infty$ we get
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|f-f_n\|_{\infty} 
\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty}\limsup_{m\to\infty}\|f_n-f_m\|_{\infty}
=\lim_{m,n\to\infty}\|f_n-f_m\|_{\infty}=0$$ since $(f_n)$ is uniformly Cauchy. Hence, $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

**b.** It remains to show that $f$ is continuous. Let's leave the verification up to the reader.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! As for continuity I am pretty sure it follows directly from the convergence being uniform.